# Auto Detect NodeJS application without Port number dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

I have two applications A and B  in Node Js and application B wants to communicate with application A.

Now Application A  selects its port dynamically during run time. So how Application B can discover on which Port application A is running?

Comment: You would need some mediator between them on a static port. Application `A` could register itself in the mediator and then application `B` could request the port of application `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle an event in app A and app B for **ECONNREFUSED**  before starting your server in express which will take care of the port in used.if you see this error then just change the port number dynamically which will be true for both apps.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and came up with solution which is **"dns-discovery"** and **"openport"**

First Check which port is open in your system  using **"openport"** and then use **"dns-discoverry"**.

**Application A**

```
var op = require('openport');
op.find(
    {
        startingPort: 8050,
        endingPort: 8999
    },
    function (err, port) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
        console.log('opened port is:::::::::' + port);
        ServerStart(port);
    }
);

function ServerStart(port) {
    var discovery = require('dns-discovery');
    var disc = discovery();
    disc.announce('connect-apps', port, function () {
        console.log("announcement start")
    });
    var io = require('socket.io')(port);

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('message', function (msg) {
            console.log("Response From Client::::::::::::" + msg);
            socket.send("Congratulations from Server");
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function (msg) {
            console.log("We are disconnected");
        });
    })
}
```

**Application B**

```
var discovery = require('dns-discovery')
var disc = discovery()
disc.lookup('connect-apps', function () {
    console.log('Server Lookup Started:::::::::::::::::::')
})
disc.on('peer', function (name, peer) {
    console.log("Server found:::::::::" + peer.host + ':::' + peer.port);
    var ws = 'ws://' + peer.host + ':' + peer.port;
    var socket = require('socket.io-client')(ws, { forceNew: true });
    socket.io.opts.transports = ['polling', 'websocket'];
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('connected');
        socket.send('Hello from Client 1::::::::Vishal Shori Machine');
    });
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log("response again::::::::::::" + msg);
    });
    disc.destroy();
})
```

**For Reference :**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/openport

https://github.com/mafintosh/dns-discovery